# Convert js to php

Tags: javascript

I have this js snippet but I can't convert to PHP because I can't find a function with an index like js snippet in PHP

```js
let productId = [13,14];
let unit = [1,2];
let price = [15000, 10000];
productId.map(function (i, index){
   var arrayItem =[i , unit[index], price[index]];

   console.log( arrayItem);
})
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp use `array_map`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using map for this in the first place... you never use its return value. A traditional for loop is better for this

Answer (score 1):

```php
$productID = [13, 14];
$unit = [1,2];
$price = [15000,10000];
$arrayItem = []

for($i = 0, $size = count($productID); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    $arrayItem[$i] = [$i, $unit[$i], $price[$]);
    print_r($arrayItem[$i];
}
```